# My Huawei E173 dongle works in Ubuntu 12.04 not in 13.10

Tags: wireless

As the topic mentions, I have this problem. I use the normal "connect" option on the right hand top and I am able to successfully connect to the network using 12.04 but not using 13.10.

May I know why and if there is a solution?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Follow these simple steps.

From here: [Hoovam:Ubuntu 13.10 Not detecting dongles](http://hoovam.blogspot.com/2014/04/ubuntu-1310-not-detecting-any-dongles.html)

Step 1 :
First thing first, plug in your dongle :)

Step 2 : 
Click the network indicator in your menu bar.
You will  see that Ubuntu 13.10 is not showing the 'Enable Mobile Broadband' option in the network indicator.

Step 3 :
Open the 'Disks' application.

Step 4 :
You will see some 'Disk Drivers' listed under 'Devices' list.
Eject the 'CD Drive (dongle specific)'.

'CD Drive HUAWEI Mass Storage' in my case.

Step 5 :
Within 1 minute, you will see the option 'Enable Mobile Broadband' in your network indicator. Go ahead and connect. Done.

Hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Please provide a digest of this method for future reference.

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu! Although it can be useful to add a link to an answer, it would be better to briefly describe the procedure. Links come and go, and might not be available in the future.

Comment: Jacob, thanks very much for pointing this out to me. will follow your way :)